# I can't uncheck "Refuses First Responder" in interface builder

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I can't uncheck the properties under "`State`" in the `Control` section for the NSTableView:

[image]

When I click on a checkbox, the sign disappears for 1 second and then it comes back.
Could you explain me why?

Comment: from the edge of that screenshot there it looks like you are using mavericks?  which version of XCode are you using? Does this happen with all of your controls?  Does this happen to all of your xibs?  Does this happen to all of your projects?

Comment: That's not Mavericks. Look at the UI.

Comment: @MattyAyOh xCode 6.1.1, Yosemite. Not all of them.. but all tables. Not all xibs files. Not all projects.

Comment: @Patrick, I am also on 6.1.1 w/ Yosemite, and I can't seem to reproduce it.  Maybe you could send me your project file (delete the important stuff) and I could check if I can reproduce?  At least that way we can eliminate your machine being the issue.  Also have you tried programmatically setting it to refuse first responder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is that I had no Columns in the table: Column = 0. 
(I'm adding the columns programmatically).

Still this is a bug in Interface Builder user interface.

Answer (score 2):

Able to uncheck with XCode 6 on 10.10.

From your image attached, your line break mode is shown as invalid value. This could have happened when you tried to edit the source xml of xib.

Did you try selecting a valid Line break mode. Also what version of XCode are you using.

[image: XCode 6.1.1]

Comment: Hi, I didn't edit the source xml. This is what's strange. I'm using xCode 6.1.1

Comment: The file was initially developed in xCode3.. then 4..5... so it could be the conversion caused the problem, but still I couldn't find any example on the web.

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue. If Yes, is it possible for you to delete the table and add a new table and try if this works. Even after this, if you have issue, can you share the xib file which you have issue removing other components and retaining only the table with issue.

Comment: I found the solution, check the answer